# Spring Boot Actuator in the traditional container

Tags: spring-boot

Can we use the Spring Boot Actuator in the traditional shared container within the context of an application? If so, how would be the configuration look like?

I have tried it by bootstrapping `EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration`. However, could not map mvc urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you from just using it as a dependency. Any Spring Boot app should be able to use actuator features out of the box.